# I need help setting up my wireless card driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, apt, wine

First, I am **new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.**.. I am trying to install my wireless card driver (because the system don't recognize it) but the driver is an .exe so I am trying to install Wine in order to use it. The problem I have is every time I try to follow the instructions according to the Winehq web page I receive this problem: when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` it says:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve that or my main problem with the WiFi card?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use this to see what's locking that file `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

Comment: You are presenting two issues, the lock is minor and is simply as a result of a process locking it. And can be identified with the command a gave above been run from the command line. __Please wine does not install drivers on linux__ so restructure your question to pick the main point. The lock can be removed by you or when the process ends.

Comment: For the WiFi issue: Please add the stdout of `sudo iwconfig` and `sudo lsusb` (if the device is USB) or `sudo lspci | grep Network`(if the device is an internal WiFi card).

Answer (score 0):

Wine isn't used to install drivers.  Go to "Additional Drivers" in settings, and install any drivers not installed.  Note that you will need an alternate connection temporarily (e.g. plugging in to the router via an Ethernet cable) for this to work.

Comment: i already did what u telling me to do, Ive connected my PC into a Ethernet cable, waited few minutes and than updated all cashes/drivers/any updates that poped up. but my edimax 7711ln netowrk card driver didnt poped up and even after i lefted the computer plugged over night it didnt so im clue less to the problem.... so it aint working.... the 1 time it worked in the ubuntu PC was when the usb iso stick was connected.... after than its never worked or any drivers whown...